# VS C# connected to mySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

I am very new in C# and now try to find online resource to connect VS C# to mySQL database at server 'localhost', with userid 'root', and password '****', the databasename is 'dlht'.

1.I copied a line of code from youtube and it works:

```
 this.stockTableAdapter.Fill(this.blhsDataSet.stock);
```

Can anyone explain to me what exactly this is doing? There is no place to put server, password, userid etc... How can it work?

2. I tried to use the online tutorials to connect to mySQL database

[ZetCode C#Tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlcsharptutorial)

```
    string cs = @"server=localhost;userid=root;
        password=****;database=dlht";

    MySqlConnection conn = null;

    try 
    {
      conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
      conn.Open();
      Console.WriteLine("MySQL version : {0}", conn.ServerVersion);

    } catch (MySqlException ex) 
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}",  ex.ToString());

    } finally 
    {          
      if (conn != null) 
      {
          conn.Close();
      }
    }
```

I run this code at Form1.cs at VS C#. It is always stuck at :

```
conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
```

Why? Thank you so much!

Comment: ad 2: what does 'it is always stuck' mean? do you get an excpetion?

Comment: there is a really good link out there that gives excellent examples on how to format a connection string depending on what database you're using
[C# ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the proper way to connect to MySql database is this

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```